# how do you make this symbol in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I don't know how to define this so here's an image of what I'm trying to write:

[image]

How do I write the subscript and superscript? What is the superscript line called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\mu'_n = \operatorname{E}(X^n) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x^n dF(x)
```

I haven't tested it in LaTeX but it works in MathJax at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
a_{subscript}
a^{superscript}
a_{subscript}^{andsuperscript}
```

Comment: Great! Any idea how to make that line on top of the mu? I'd search for it online but I don't even know what it's called.